# Upgrading Google eclipse plugin broke my project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

After upgrading Google plugin for Eclipse to the latest version of Eclipse 4.5, Eclipse is reporting the following error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'appengine-application'.  appengine-application.xml   /bootstrap/META-INF line 2  XML Problem

My appengine-application.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<appengine-application xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>myappname</application>
</appengine-application>
```

It is also not showing the "deploy to plugin" option. I think the above issue is related to this. I am unable to revert the google plugin since Eclipse is unable to find some of the packages needed to revert. Kind of stuck for a day now. Any suggestions?